# How do I connect Clash of Clans to my Google account?

Tags: clash-of-clans, android

I have a Level 7 Town Hall in *Clash of Clans*, and I realized that it is not connected to any of my Google accounts. What should I do? Is there a way to connect it to my account?

Answer (score 1):

To connect your village to Google+, open the Google+ app on your device and make sure you are logged in.

After this, open Clash of Clans and go to the in-game setting. Press the Google+ sign in button to connect your village to Google+. The Google+ Button should change from Disconnected to **Connected**.

See the images below:

[image: Connect to google +]

Comment: NOTE: As of approximately February 24, 2016 Google Play started using a GamerID. There are many reported problems with this including switching between accounts.